# Do people in Wonderland know the power of true love in Once Upon a Time in Wonderland?

Tags: once-upon-a-time, once-upon-a-time-in-wonderland

If they know, why didn't the Knave kiss Anastasia when she died? And why didn't Alice kiss Cyrus when he fainted at the end of S01EP12?!! Does the power of true love apply in Wonderland?

Comment: True love can break any spell, but not bring back the dead.

Answer (score 3):

I see a few basic flaws in the question:

1)  True love's kiss can break any curse.  Death is not a curse, and neither is fainting.

2)  Among the rules of magic is that the dead cannot be brought back to life.  The curse-breaking power of true love's kiss is a type of magic, and so, it could not bring the dead back to life even if the death was caused by a curse.

3)  Regardless of the above, Jafar was not allowing the Knave near Anastasia's body.

> That said, true love's kiss does make an appearance in 1x13, the final episode of the series.